# Spring data Page/Pageable returns duplicates on large data sets?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When operating on large data sets, Spring Data presents two abstractions: `Stream` and `Page`. We've been using `Stream` for awhile and had no issues, but recently I wanted to try a paginated approach and ran into a reliability issue.

Consider the following:

```
@Entity
public class MyData {
}

public interface MyDataRepository extends JpaRepository<MyData, UUID> {
}

@Component
public class MyDataService {
    private MyDataRepository repository;

    // Bridge between a Reactive service and a transactional / non-reactive database call
    @Transactional
    public void getAllMyData(final FluxSink<MyData> sink) {
        final Pageable firstPage = PageRequest.of(0, 500);

        Page<MyData> page = repository.findAll(firstPage);

        while (page != null && page.hasContent()) {
            page.getContent().forEach(sink::next);

            if (page.hasNext()) {
                page = repository.findAll(page.nextPageable());
            }
            else {
                page = null;
            }
        }

        sink.complete();
    }
}
```

Using two Postgres 9.5 databases, the source database had close to 100,000 rows while the destination was empty. The example code was then used to copy from the source to the destination. At the end I would find that my destination database had far smaller row count than the source.

- Run as a springboot app
- The flux doing the copy was using 4-6 threads in parallel (for speed)
- Total run time of at least an hour (max was 2 hours)

As it turns out, I was eventually processing the same rows multiple times (and missing other rows as a result). This lead me to discovering a fix that others had already ran into, where you should provide a `Sort.by("")` argument.

After changing the service to use:

```
// Make our pages sorted by the PKEY
final Pageable firstPage = PageRequest.of(0, 500, Sort.by("id"));
```

I found that while it GREATLY helped, I would still process multiple rows (from losing about half the rows to only seeing ~12 duplicates). When I use a `Stream` instead, I have no issues.

Does anyone have any explanation for what is going on? I don't seem to have any duplicates come through until the test has been running for at least 10-15min, which almost leads me to believe that there is some kind of session or other timeout happening (either in the client, or on the database) that causes the hiccups. But I'm really far out of my knowledge area for troubleshooting it further heh.

Comment: Is `MyDataService` a singleton bean?

Comment: @Brian Yes it is. I've updated the example code with an `@Component`

Comment: Is your database static or are there reads/writes/updates going on at the same time?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The source database is in a shared environment, but it wasn't being actively used at the time - its possible some updates might have occurred to the rows, but no rows were inserted/removed (no changes to PKEYs)

Comment: Have you tried logging out the page offsets/limit to see if they are being duplicated at this stage? Not having details on the rest of your flow, I'd say that the drops are due to the fact that you are pushing all data out without regard for demand (backpressure). If downstream is not keeping up, it is possible that your implementation is dropping records. As far as duplicates, again, would have to see your flow. This has some useful information: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.

Comment: I have dealt with similar situations (the implementations are proprietary / not owned by me) so I can't post them, but following that link, you can look at producing a Flux, and provide (sink::next) the records with consideration for the demand (push/pull) vs a push only, with an OverflowStrategy.ERROR or OverflowStrategy.BUFFER.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe its backpressure related; not only does using a `Stream` implementation work 100% correctly, but when using `Page` I record "processing" the exact row count of the source database. So from my code/handler perspective, I handled all rows - its just that duplicates took the place of others

Comment: @mrusinak did you ever find the problem or solution to this?

Comment: @ChrisSavory No, sadly - I have not looked into it any deeper since this post (and just used a Stream as my immediate solution/workaround)

Comment: We also found that adding the `Sort.by` helped

Comment: I've encoutered very similar problem, I use sorted Pageable in a loop (`while page.hasNext()`) and I got apx 720 000 records while the DB table has only apx 430 000 records. Has anyone know how to fix it?